# String string = request.getParameter("data") is null

Tags: java, ajax, json, servlets

I am writing a servlet that will accept POST data coming from an AJAX request.

Here is the code I send from the client:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "urlservlet",
            data: "{type:'" + "country" + 
            "', country:'" + $('#country').val() +
            "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response) {

            }
```

And this is the servlet code:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                      throws ServletException, IOException {
    string test = request.getParameter("type");
}
```

But the thing is I always get the type equal to null. I don't know why.

Kindly help me.

Comment: Your title says `getP(data)`, whereas your code says `getP(type)`. What is the actual problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are writing JSON to your request body and expecting request parameters. From the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29):

> Returns the value of a request parameter as a String, or null if the
>   parameter does not exist. Request parameters are extra information
>   sent with the request. **For HTTP servlets, parameters are contained in
>   the query string or posted form data.**

You haven't posted form data and don't have a query string.

What you want is to read the HTTP request body with `HtppServletRequest#getInputStream()` and parse the JSON to extract your element.

Comment: oh okay. please elaborate more. please. :)

Comment: @pepsi Elaborate on what subject? There are keywords in my answer that will help you find what you want.

Comment: Thanks man, appreciated your time. just asking about a sample code. since I am very new to java.:)

Comment: I fixed this using the 
contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
then just get it on the server side using the getParameterMap() method and just manipulate the string to make it a valid json data. :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is as @Sotirios describes. However, I would solve it by using a Java REST framework on the server side like [RESTEasy](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.4.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html), [Spring MVC](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch18s02.html), or [Restlet](http://restlet.org/). It is preferable to use an abstraction so you can focus on your business logic rather than low-level details of the `Servlet` API.

And a JSON serializer/deserializer like [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) to avoid dealing with the low-level details of parsing JSON. Jackson as well as its alternatives integrate seamlessly with the REST frameworks I mentioned.

I like good abstractions.

Comment: Jackson has made me bang my head against the wall for 8 hours, because the error handling is terrible at best